# как можно сделать так чтобы бот писал дату выданной роли пользователю тип когда пользователь был принят на роль Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

как можно сделать так чтобы бот писал дату выданной роли пользователю тип когда пользователь был принят на роль?

Answer (score 0):

Дискорд по умолчанию не хранит информацию о том, когда и какая роль была выдана пользователю. Вы можете использовать метод [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WSEventType), затем получитить получить событие из журнала аудита (обновление ролей пользотеля) [`memberRoleUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogAction).
Таким образом вы можете получить информацию о выданной роли, далее необходимо определиться с хранением данной информации (База данных, JSON файл и т.д.), решить будите ли выперезаписывать дату выдачи роли или будуте хранить всю историю изменений.

Вот пример, как можно получить информацию о выданной роли, к сожалению с дальнейшей проработкой вопроса помочь не могу, так это требует больше деталей от Вас и будет весьма ресурсоемкой задачей :)

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(oldMember.roles.size < newmember.roles.size) {
        const fetchedLogs = await oldMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE',
    });
    
        const roleAddLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
        if (!roleAddLog ) return;
        const { executor, target, extra } = roleAddLog;
        console.log(`Role ${extra.name} added to ${<@target.id>} by ${<@executor.id>}`)
    }
});
```